# AD web app works on local host but asks credentials in Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm very new to Azure and don't know anything about Active Directory.

I have created a Razor web page with Active Directory authentication (just plain new Razor page with AD on Visual Studio). It works on localhost fine.
When I published my web page on azure and followed this tutorial to register my page on Azure AD:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core
When I go to my web page it still asks for credentials and when I enter it asks again. I just followed the instructions hadn't changed anything, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment for asp.net core application .
I granted the permissions on behalf of user
[image]

In startup.cs, make sure        app.UseAuthentication();  app.UseAuthorization();  are in order

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            ...

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
          ...
        }
```

[image]

- Cookie management maybe issue in the older version of OWIN where it can’t  recognize an authenticated request from Azure AD and keeps on sending the request back to Azure AD for login leading to the infinite loop issue.
  Use one of the new cookie manager classes,

  ```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
    { 
        AuthenticationType = "Cookies", 
        CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager() 
    });
  ```
- Also make sure the permissions offline_access, openid ,profile,user.read are granted admin consent.

[image]

Also check this  [SO ref](https://You%20can%20also%20check%20this%20c#%20-%20How%20to%20use%20both%20Azure%20AD%20authentication%20and%20Identity%20on%20ASP.NET%20Core%203?%20-%20Stack%20Overflow)

[image]